# Load WP Query with Ajax

Tags: wp-query, ajax

I have a website that has around 700 requests, and takes a while to load and I do a query that queries 600 posts, as it is a one page site.

What I am thinking is to load the basic website first, then to load the Queries with Ajax afterwards.

Is this doable?

Comment: It's hard to give any advice based on this info, but... I would recommend you to rethink your approach - 700 requests is really a lot and querying 600 posts also sounds like a horror for your server...

Comment: The homepage is about 30Megabytes (I am using a preloader). What do you think the right approach would be?

Comment: I don't have any brief or knowledge about that website nor its purpose, so it's really hard to give any advice. But site that has 30 MB and makes 600 requests doesn't make any sense to me... Google will hate it... Your hosting will hate it... And I don't believe it will help its owner...